# Monoid Instance for `a -> b`

Tags: haskell

I attempted to implement a `Monoid'` instance for a function `a -> b`.

```
class Monoid' a where
    mempty  :: a -> a
    mappend :: a -> a -> a

instance Monoid' (a -> b) where
    mempty  f   = f
    mappend f g = g . f
```

Please critique it for correctness and style.

In addition, I'm curious how `mappend` should be implemented. Should `f` or `g` be applied first?

Comment: I can't see how this would typecheck, given the usual definition of `Monoid`. Can you post your definition of `Monoid` as well?

Comment: Same one here - http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Monoid.html. my above code did not compile since Data.Monoid already has it

Comment: Try defining `Monoid` without importing `Data.Monoid` -- e.g. [here](http://ideone.com/7dMy3c).

Comment: Thanks. So `g . f` doesn't make sense since it does not type check. Hmm, so how can I "combine" an `(a -> b)` and `(a -> b)` to get an `(a -> b)`...

Comment: This question should probably be closed until the code works. Feel free to head over to chat and I'll try to help out.

Comment: Thanks mjolka but I'm going to sleep. I'll stop on chat tomorrow at night (and there after). Also I flagged it to be closed temporarily

Answer (score 2):

Something nice about hackage help/documentation pages like the one you linked: you can go straight to the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-Monoid.html) by clicking on the links on the right side of the page.  Looking at the source, there is an instance for `Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)`, which is not quite exactly what you're trying to do, since it restricts `b` to types with a `Monoid` implementation.  It uses a nice trick where it implements this monoid in terms of the other monoid.

The Data.Monoid code:

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) where
    mempty _ = mempty
    mappend f g x = f x `mappend` g x
```

If you have any difficulty understanding it, keep in mind that the `mempty` and `mappend` functions are for different monoids on the left hand side than they are for the right hand side.

I can think of 2 ways of getting 2 `a -> b`s to combine: throw away the first one, or throw away the second one.  Neither seems similar to what you're trying to do (or particularly useful).

Besides the (already noted) problem that `.` as an implementation of `mappend` won't typecheck, there's another problem: `mempty`.  As written, it'll typecheck, but the type signature of your `mempty` is `a -> a`, while it should be just `a`.  `mempty` is a value in the monoid.

I'd be tempted to change the definition to `mempty = id`, but `id :: a -> a` not `a -> b`.  You could try to make a constant function that just returns some particular `b`, but since you have no idea what type `b` will be, that's not possible.

In general, haskell's type system is very nice -- not only can it catch type errors, but it can serve as documentation, provide a bit of heuristic guidance and help you organize your thoughts.  When something doesn't typecheck, it means what you're trying to do doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: by defining `mempty _ = mempty`, does it not just recursively call itself endlessly?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: No, there are 2 different `mempty`s here.  There's the one that we're defining, of type `a -> b`, and another one that we're using in the definition, of type `b`.  If type `b` happens to be a list, `mempty` is just `[]`.  We don't know enough about type `b` to be sure it isn't a function, but unlike `a -> b` which is definitely a function, `b` could just be a value.

Answer (score 2):

What your code says is "given two arbitrary types `a` and `b`, the functions `a -> b` form a monoid".  This is not very meaningful, as the resulting definitions for `mempty` and `mappend` are not very meaningful.  In particular, something to the effect of `mempty = const undefined` is required.

What I think you were looking for is [`Control.Category`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Category.html).  A category can be seen as a generalisation of a monoid where not all elements can be combined.  Haskell types and functions naturally form a category, with `id` being the identity for each type and `.` being composition of functions.